# Can I check whether DependencyProperty changed by Server or Control (Silverlight)

Tags: vb.net, silverlight

I have a custom control in Silverlight with a DependencyProperty.
If the value of the property is changed by the control itself, that's fine.  However, if the value is changed on the server, the control has to do a reload of its contents.

So, in my PropertyChangedCallback routine, I want to be able to check whether it was the control who changed the value, or it was changed on the server (in which case, the contents need to be reloaded).

The control is a text box, and when it changes I'm doing a SetValue to change the DependencyProperty value, but the PropertyChangedCallback routine doesn't know it was the control who called it, or the server.

How can I check where the PropertyChangedCallback was called from?

Dependency Property:

```
Public Shared HtmlHolderProperty As DependencyProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("HtmlHolder",
                                    GetType(String),
                                    GetType(HTMLEditor),
                                    New PropertyMetadata(Nothing, New PropertyChangedCallback(AddressOf OnHtmlHolderChanged)))
```

Dependency Property Changed handler:

```
Private Shared Sub OnHtmlHolderChanged(d As DependencyObject, e As DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)
    Dim hte As HTMLEditor = DirectCast(d, HTMLEditor)
    Dim newhtml As String = If(e.NewValue Is Nothing, "", e.NewValue)
    Dim oldhtml As String = If(e.OldValue Is Nothing, "", e.OldValue)

    If newhtml <> m_HtmlHolder AndAlso ControlUpdate > ControlUpdateTracker Then
        hte.htb.Load(Format.HTML, newhtml)
        ControlUpdateTracker = ControlUpdateTracker + 1
    End If
    m_HtmlHolder = newhtml
End Sub
```

Binding:

```
Private Sub CreateBindings(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles MyBase.Loaded
    Dim control As HTMLEditor = DirectCast(sender, HTMLEditor)
    Dim context As IContentItem = DirectCast(control.DataContext, IContentItem)
    Dim binding As Data.Binding
    binding = New Data.Binding("Value") With {
                        .Source = context,
                        .Mode = Data.BindingMode.TwoWay
                    }
    Me.SetBinding(HTMLEditor.HtmlHolderProperty, binding)
End Sub
```

Control _ContentChanged:

```
Private Sub htb_ContentChanged(sender As Object, e As RichTextBoxEventArgs) Handles htb.ContentChanged
    Dim htb As Liquid.RichTextBox = DirectCast(sender, Liquid.RichTextBox)
    SetValue(HtmlHolderProperty,htp.HTML)
End Sub
```

Comment: +1 for adding the code: Your `htb_ContentChanged` handler is calling `SetValue` directly... is that your intention or did you want to go through the setter?

Comment: I've tried it with SetValue and with HtmlHolder = but both with the same results unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you use the setter when setting the value from the control?

If so, simply set a flag before and after the SetValue call in the setter. Then you can see if the change was from the control itself inside the event handler for the dependency property.

**Apologies for C# code, as you stated VB.Net, but you get the idea.**

```
protected bool LocallySet {get;set;}

public bool MyProperty
{
    get { return (bool)GetValue(MyDPProperty); }
    set 
    { 
        LocallySet = true;
        SetValue(MyDPProperty, value);
        LocallySet = false;
    }
}
```

If you are having trouble with lots of overlapping control events, try a counter instead:

```
protected int _LocallySetCount;

public bool MyProperty
{
    get { return (bool)GetValue(MyDPProperty); }
    set 
    { 
        _LocallySetCount++;
        SetValue(MyDPProperty, value);
        _LocallySetCount--;
    }
}
```

The count will be non-zero if you are processing one or more control changes.

*It would help if you could post the code for your property.*

Comment: Yep, I tried that, but it doesn't work consistently...
I think it's something to do with how the control works - it's a textbox (richtext) and if you're typing fast, I think it might be firing one _Changed event before the preceding one has finished (I'm not even sure if that's possible)

Comment: Actually the SetValue might wind up delayed if you are not on the UI thread when you set the property... Are you in the UI thread when you set it in the control?

Comment: If it is an overlapping change problem, use a counter instead of a flag and inc/dec the value. If it is non-zero you are processing events from the control.

Comment: Yep, that's a great idea, I didn't think of that, but it's not working :S
Every now and then a change in the control is picked up by the PropertyChangedCallback with the counter=0.  I've tried moving the decrement from the _ControlChanged event and into the PropertyChangedCallback, but it's made no difference.

Comment: Sounds like something else is going awry... are you able to post mode code/Xaml to make a working example of the problem?

Comment: It may be a problem with the control I'm using, it's the Vectorlight.net RichTextBox and I'm making a control out of that which will expose a bindable "HTML" property (rather than the text/XAML that it currently exposes).  That's why, when the value is changed from the server, I need to do a reload on the control.  The reload of the control causes the cursor to jump to the top of the textbox, which is fine if the value was changed from the server, but useless when you're typing!  I think the Vectorlight control is perhaps not behaving properly somewhere, but I can't work it out.

Comment: Ah... "3rd party control" = "whole different kettle of fish". Will give it some more thought.

Comment: If you know of another decent (free/ish) Silverlight richtext control that can accept HTML (and return HTML) then it would save us all a lot of problems ;)  This is what happens when you don't want to spend $1000 on properly developed stuff :D